# Как подсветить слова в тексте на js?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть обычный текст в переменной `text_pr`. В другой переменной `arr` находятся слова, которые необходимо подсветить, т.е. добавить класс `.text_red` (css-класс для подсветки красным цветом).
Как это реализовать?

Код = https://jsfiddle.net/tb2vv2kk/1/

```js
var text_pr = "Здесь простой текст со словами которые нужно подсветить, добавить класс red, Здесь простой текст со словами которые нужно подсветить, добавить класс red";

var arr = ["текст", "нужно", "red", "четыре"];


$("#button").click(function() {

  //$().addClass('text_red');
  $('#text_rez').html(text_pr);

});
```

```css
#button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3BA4C7;
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 6px 18px;
}
#button:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
.text_red {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Показать</div>
<br>
<div id="text_rez"></div>
```

Comment: Прочитайте про метод `indexOf()`

Comment: надо создать document.createTextRange(). потом findText и pasteHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте следующее в JS

```
jQuery.each(arr, function(ind, txt) {
    var re = new RegExp(txt,"g");
    text_pr = text_pr.replace(re, '<span class="text_red">'+txt+'</span>');
});
```

перед `$('#text_rez').html(text_pr);`

Код пролистывает через массив. Используя regex, находит нужные слова и обрамляет их в `<span class="text_red">`.

Однако есть один момент.
Вам надо поменять в примере массив и быть аккуратным с именем класса.
В Вашем массиве есть элемент `red`, который конфликтует с именем класса `text-red`. Т.е. когда в массиве очередь доходит до элемента `red`, он заменяется в тексте, ломая ранее вставленные `span`.

```js
var text_pr = "Здесь простой текст с словами которые нужно подсветить, добавить класс red, Здесь простой текст с словами которые нужно подсветить, добавить класс red";

var arr = ["текст", "нужно", "класс", "четыре"];


$("#button").click(function() {

jQuery.each(arr, function(ind, txt) {
    var re = new RegExp(txt,"g");
    text_pr = text_pr.replace(re, '<span class="text_red">'+txt+'</span>');
});
  $('#text_rez').html(text_pr);

});
```

```css
#button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3BA4C7;
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 6px 18px;
}
#button:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
.text_red {
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Показать</div>
<br>
<div id="text_rez"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    if(text_pr.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1){
        // выставляем класс
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.